# Doing a diagram with tikz

Tags: diagrams, arrows, tikz-cd

I'm trying to do a diagram. In this code, the diagonal lines have a good size, but i don't know how to make the horizontal lines bigger. Thanks for your advices!

```
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={\rightarrow}]
& \mbox{Topos {\'e}tale} & \\
\mbox{N{\'u}mero} \arrow{ur} & \leftrightarrows & \mbox{Espacio}\arrow{ul} \\
\end{tikzcd}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rr` and `ll` as arguments to `\arrow`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
& \mbox{Topos {\'e}tale} & \\
\mbox{N{\'u}mero} \arrow[ur]\arrow[rr,yshift=2pt]& & \mbox{Espacio}\arrow[ul]\arrow[ll,yshift=-2pt] \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```